# Left join with conditions, unknown column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, left-join

I have a table `news`. Fields `title`, `text`, `id`.
Also i have a table `news_notifications`. Fields `id`, `user_id`, `news_id`.

I need to query all news from `news` and also join  `news_modifications` to check if the user has already read news or not .

But when I try to left join `news_modifications` by `user_id` MySQL throws an error:

> `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'on clause'`, where `1` is the user id for session.

I'm using laravel, so my full query here.

```
    $news = DB::table('news')  
        ->leftJoin('news_notifications', function($join){
            $join->on('news.id', '=', 'news_notifications.news_id');
            $join->on('news_notifications.user_id', '=', 1);
        })

        ->select(['news.id', 'news.created_at',  'news.title', 'news.text', 'news_notifications.user_id AS readed'])
        ->orderBy('news.created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

When I try to use `where`, news with other users notifications deleted from results.

```
    $news = DB::table('news')  
        ->leftJoin('news_notifications', 'news.id', '=', 'news_notifications.news_id')
        ->where(function($where){
            $where->where('news_notifications.user_id', Auth::id())
                ->orWhere('news_notifications.user_id', NULL);
        })
        ->select(['news.id', 'news.created_at',  'news.title', 'news.text', 'news_notifications.user_id AS readed'])
        ->orderBy('news.created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try protecting the guilty 1 which is considered as a column name and not as a value. quotes could do it. you may need 2 levels of quotes to be sure it is a value and not a column when it reachs the database

Comment: Well, you should use a column name instead of the static value.

Comment: if you wish to use a static value directly. Use where condition like:
$news = DB::table('news')  
        ->leftJoin('news_notifications', function($join){
            $join->on('news.id', '=', 'news_notifications.news_id');            
        })
       ->where('news_notifications.user_id', '=', 1);

Comment: `where('news_notifications.user_id', '=', Auth::id())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of this can be solved using a relationship on the models and a with statement instead of left join.

News:

```
public function news-notifications($query){
    $query->hasMany(News_Notification::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

News_notification

```
public function news($query){
    $query->belongsTo(News::class, 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

With clause:

```
$news = DB::table('news')
    ->with(['news_notifications', function($query){ 
        $query->where('news.id', '=', 'news_notifications.news_id')
            ->where('news_notifications.user_id', '=', 1); 
    }) 
    ->select(['news.id', 'news.created_at', 'news.title', 'news.text', 'news_notifications.user_id AS readed']) 
    ->orderBy('news.created_at', 'desc')->paginate
```

**Update:**
As requested in the comments, this is some information on using `with` in a query in Eloquent.  If you're not familiar, eager loading is essentially loading data in table B that you think you'll need based on the conditions you're constraining table A to.  In this case, we're going to load all results from `news_notifications` that have an id matching the user_id to the id column in the `news` table.  Just like a left join, it returns all matching results from `news`,and all matching from `news_notification` within that group.

This produces an object that you can navigate with arrow syntax.  For instance, if you wanted to access the `news_id` column from a matching relationship, you could use:

```
$news->news_notification->pluck('news_id');
```

That would return an array of all matching news ids from each `news_notification` object.  If there is only ever one user_id to id match, we can remove the pluck.  First we'd have to change the `news` model again to:

```
public function news-notifications($query){
    $query->hasOne(News_Notification::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

The `hasOne` relationship implies a `first()` instead of a `get()` when eager loading.  Because it only returns one result now, the subtable will not be an array of objects, just an object.  That makes the syntax:

```
$news->news_notification->news_id;
```

There are a lot of other ways to manipulate a relationship.  For instance, `whereHas('tableName', function($query){//tableB where constraints})` is actually like an inner join, in that whatever results you get from the inner query will also constrain the outer query.

I would suggest reading more at the following link:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm using relationships in simple queries, but i can't undestand this clause with `with` statement. Is it possible for you to explain or point where to read about it? Thank you again.

Comment: Hey @Maximus98, I just updated my answer with a good amount of information and a link for further reading.  If you have any issues, let me know, otherwise don't forget to mark as answered for future reference!